# searchform.php not included by get_search_form when using wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: search

I have a category dropdown within my searchform.php, coding within Wordpress 4.x.  It has worked without issue for a couple of years.

An issue has arisen with Wordpress 5.2.

My `searchform.php` includes a modified form for the search and a dropdown menu for categories using `wp_dropdown_categories()`.

`get_search_form()` outputs nothing.

A précis of `searchform.php`;

```
<div>
  $args = array (
  ...some arguments...
  );
  wp_dropdown_categories($args);
 <form>... search code
 ...</form>
```

if I remove `wp_dropdown_categories()` and insert it in the calling page before `get_search_form()` it works perfectly.

There are no PHP errors or warnings.

Whereas separating the two function calls is no problem, I am curious as to what might be happening and under what circumstances `get_search_form()` can fail without returning any error.

Comment: ps if anyone can think of a clearer title, please feel free

Comment: Can you share the full code of searchform.php?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the use of a variable called $args within 'searchform.php' causes the searchform to output nothing.